# ERR value is not an integer or out of range

Tags: lua, stackexchange.redis

I have this code in a lua script which I run from .net.

```
 const string script = " if redis.call('EXISTS', '{0}') == 1 then" +
                              " local user = redis.call('get','{0}')" +
                              " local value = cjson.decode(user)" +
                              " value['UserPreferences'] = cjson.decode('{1}')" +
                              " value['Timestamp'] = cjson.decode('{2}')" +
                              " local val=cjson.encode(value)" +
                              " redis.call('set', '{0}', val)" +
                              " redis.call('EXPIRE', '{0}','{3}')" +
                              " end";

        var redisScript = string.Format(script, "User_" + userId, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userPreferences), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.UtcNow), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisKeyExpiryTime"]);
      await Cache.ScriptEvaluateAsync(redisScript);
```

This returns the error :

Error: ERR value is not an integer or out of range

please give some feedback to solve the issue.

Comment: Does the error message say where the error is occurring?

Comment: The error was coming from the lua server. BTW I get the issue, it was some special character that was causing the script to fail at the time of compilation.